# How can I remove an object from the end of a line of objects connected to each other? (Java)

Tags: java, object, loops, while-loop

In other words, I have line of Dancer objects.

```
public class Dancer {

    private String name;
    private Dancer next;

    public Dancer(String nameInput, Dancer followingDancer){
        name = nameInput;
        next = followingDancer;
    }
```

I have setters and getters for these.

To string these along, I have a CongaLine.

```
public class CongaLine {

    private Dancer head; // first dancer in the conga line.

    public CongaLine() {
        head = null;
    }
```

So, using a while loop to find the next to last Dancer, how would I find an extract the last Dancer from a CongaLine?

My current method, which is flawed, looks like this:

```
public String removeFromEnd() {
    String removed = null;
    // For multiple dancers, find the penultimate and remove its "next"
    while (head.getNext() != null) {
        if (head.getNext().getNext() == null){
        removed = head.getNext().getName();
        head.setNext(null);
        }
    }
    // In the case of only one dancer, remove that dancer.
    if (head != null && head.getNext() == null) {
        removed = head.getName();
        head = null;
    }
    return removed;
}
```

Comment: In your class CongaLine, why don't have a field with type of [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)? something like private List<Dancer> dancer = new LinkedList<Dancer>(); then you can get the dancer.getLast() for example.

Comment: That would make it too easy. I need to do it without altering the pre-defined classes.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm I could give you the exact code (it's only a few lines) however I think since you're doing this for learning it's better to give a couple of hints instead:

- Think about what *property* the last dancer has that can be used to identify it.
- Think about how you ensure that you look at all dancers so that you find the one with the right property.
- Think about what other changes need to happen (e.g. to the next-to-last dancer), and how you ensure that these changes always take place.

Comment: Don't feel bad - it's all part of the learning experience! I've been coding 26 years and my code still goes wrong all the time.... the important thing is exercising your thinking and trying different solutions so that you find good ways to solve the problems when they occur. :-)

Comment: The property would be its "next". It would be null. I'm not sure about the second bullet. I'm pretty sure I need to set the next to last dancer's "next" to null. I also need to return either null or the removed dancer. I just can't grasp what I'm missing in my method.

Comment: Good start! Now maybe try writing a method "isLastDancer()" in your Dancer class that returns a boolean. If you separate out some of the complexity into clearly named functions it will usually make it easier for you to debug the logic.

Comment: Yup, I'm still getting nowhere. I'm probably trying to make it harder than it is. Either way, I can't get the method to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). You'll have to loop through the dancers until you reach the end of the conga line:

```
Dancer d = congaLine.getHead();
while(d.getNext() != null) {
  d = d.getNext();
}
```

At the end of this `d` will be the last dancer in the congaLine. 
You'll just need to implement a getter for `next` dancer in Dancer and for the `head` dancer in CongaLine.

Comment: Several examples may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+user%3A230513+java.util.LinkedList).